# How to copy sqlite database from bundle to documents folder without losing 'many to many' relationships?

Tags: ios, core-data, file-copying

I have a sqlite database file in bundle that I want to copy to documents folder at the start of the application, but when I copy it using [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:] all of my 'many to many' relationships disappear. I am aware that there is a bug with 'migratePersistentStore' method which removes all of many to many relationships, but I can't believe that copying file also does the same thing. Also, when I copy file from bundle to desktop using Finder, file copies fine (with all relationships intact), but when I use NSFileManager to do the same thing, the relationships are gone. Any help with this would be appreciated:)!

```
NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DB" ofType:@"sqlite"];

NSString *path = @"/Users/jovanstankovic/Desktop/DB.sqlite";

NSError *error;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:path error:&error];

NSLog(@"error: %@", error.userInfo);
```

Comment: Are you trying this in iOS-simulator? The path you have won't work on an iOS device since the apps are sandboxed.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying this in simulator. DB file gets copied, but when I open it using sqlite browser, I can see that the table with relationships is empty. But when I do the same with copy/paste in finder, relationship table is filled with appropriate values. Strange thing ...

Comment: Are you copying the -wal and -shm files as well?  It may be that the relationship table data is in the -wal file?

Comment: My mistake. This is what happens when you delete old file, copy a new version of file to bundle, don't check the target membership and don't use clean product. Xcode was using the previous version of my db file that was cached and didn't have relationships implemented yet. Thanks for replies, guys!